# Find the first time that value in a list surpass a value in another list

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have two lists and I want to find the index when the second list starts to have higher values than the first list.
e.g.:

> List A: [6, 9, 15, 17, 18, 20]
>
> List B: [5, 8, 14, 16, 19, 22]

The index in which list B has a value that are higher than the value in the same index in list A is 4.

I tried to use zip, and then findFirst, but I didn't know how to get the index instead of the element.

```
 Streams.zip(listA, listB, Pair::of)
.findFirst(pair-> pair.getFirst() < pair.getSecond());
```

Is there a nice way to that using Java 8?

Comment: With *surpass* you mean that it is *always* higher?

Comment: Furthermore what should be returned if no such index exists?

Comment: if you think that looping through both and comparing relatively positioned values is nice, then yes

Comment: And moreover in StackOverflow we expect the poster to explain what he has searched and done. Usually questions of the type "please do that for me" are not accepted.

Comment: hmm so maybe the definition is not accurate. I meant to find the first time list B has higher values than list A.

Comment: Why the expected index in your example is 4? B[4] -> 19 which is lower than 20

Comment: The first time? So afterwards `b` might just drop again lower than `a`?

Comment: And what have you done, show your code

Comment: @StefanWarminski: no it is element-wise comparison I guess.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem ok, thank you. Then you suppose both lists to be sorted?

Comment: @StefanWarminski, no they might not be sorted.

Comment: Then try @Holger's solution (even there is a `)` missing and you should compare to `b.get(ix)`

Comment: Thanks for all the comments. Indeed I wrote the question in a way that it was hard to understand. Sorry! Rewriting it helped me find the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course you can use streams. :-) The solution to getting back to indices is to use `IntStream.range()`:

```
     OptionalInt first = IntStream.range(0, Math.min(listA.size(), listB.size()))
            .filter(i -> listB.get(i) > listA.get(i))
            .findFirst();
     System.out.println(first);
```

This prints:

```
OptionalInt[4]
```

In a real-world use you will probably use the `OptionalInt` some way, for example its `ifPresent` or `orElse` method.

Comment: Just posted the same answer! :) Thanks!

Comment: Yes, what a timing

Answer (score 1):

I think I found a way to do it:

```
IntStream.range(0, Min(listA.size, listB.size))
     .filter(i -> listA.get(i) < listB.get(i))
     .findFirst()
     .orElse(-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
private static int getIndex(List<Integer> first, List<Integer> second) {
    int result = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < Math.min(first.size(), second.size()); ++i) {
        if (second.get(i) > first.get(i)) {
            result = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Thanks :) I was hoping to have something like skipWhile with a condition to a stream.